# RAILS 6 Ajax events and Ajax Spinner

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to show a loading animation / spinner on every Ajax request

my application.js

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  window.addAjaxLoaderHandler();
});

window.addAjaxLoaderHandler = function() {
  $(document).on('ajax:send', function() {
    $('#ajax-loader').show();
  });

  $(document).on('ajax:complete', function(){
    setTimeout(() => {$('#ajax-loader').hide();}, 100);
  });
}
```

This works perfectly, UNTIL I load a remote form by AJAX. If I submit that newly loaded form the `ajax:send` fires, but after completion (without any errors) the `ajax:complete` does not (the spinner will not be hidden).

The problem seems to be that I remove the loaded form with the ajax call.

What can I do to make this work?

I am just trying to click a link, load a form and remove the form after sending its information.

**UPDATE**

My application.html.haml (I use HAML so syntax is accordingly, so `#...` means `<div id="...">#all indented code lines#</div>`)

```
#main
  = yield

#ajax-loader
```

The form will be loaded like:

```
$('#main').append('<%= j(render(:partial => 'new', :locals => {:model => @model})) %>');
```

The problem is that `#ajax-loader` is not hidden and still shows after form is submitted.

I think the problem is, that I remove the AJAX-call triggering element. But I was hoping, that since I bound the listener to `document`, that it still triggers.

Of course in this case I just can do `$('#ajax-loader').hide();`, but I am trying to understand why `ajax:complete` is not fired.

Comment: Is #ajax-loader parte of the form? Could you provide a snippet of the HTML part or the form removal code?

Comment: Hi @PedroLudovicoBozzini, I updated my question. My problem is, not that the loader is gone, but that it is still showing

Answer (score 0):

I guess you answered your own question: the problem is that when you remove the form, so does the event listener.

You can check what event listeners still apply to your document object using
`getEventListeners(document)`. Try this on your console* after the spinner is fired and refuses to hide.

**edit: this is a Google Chrome function, might not work in other browsers, though most of them have ways to inspect the listeners on a node*

I think of these workarounds:

a) Rebinding the listeners everytime you remove a form;

b) Attaching the listener to the `window` object instead of `document`

c) If you are using jQuery Ajax you could use the `beforeSend` and `complete` properties to show and hide the spinner instead of events. If it's not jQuery Ajax there's probably a similar way to achieve the same behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
a) That seems not like a good solution, it is easier to just manually hide the loader
b) I tried that as well, but still the same problem.
c) With Rails 6.0 it is discouraged to use jQuery handlers. And it is suggested to use the Ajax-events

Comment: and I tried getEventListeners. And listener is still there, even after form is removed.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/223